# A Dedekind Eta trajectory / horocyclic flow (Reference request)

Tags: gr.group-theory, cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, nt.number-theory

I've been exploring the composition of essentially the Dedekind $\eta$-function with
parabolic Möbius transformations,

$$C_L(z,t)=\left(\frac{z}{-tz+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\eta\left(\frac{z}{-tz+1}\right)\circeq\exp(\frac{i2\pi t}{24})\: z^{\frac{1}{2}}\:\eta(z)=C_R(z,t),$$

where the symbol $\circeq$ is used to signify that equality holds only for integer $t$, and I came across the interesting parametric curves below for $z=-2+.3i$ and $-12 \leq t \leq 12$ :

$xL(t)=Real[C_L(z,t)]\:\:\:$ and $\:\:\:yL(t)=Imag[C_L(z,t)]$ and analogously for $C_R(z,t)$

[image]

$C_L(z,t)$ is annihilated by $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}-z^2\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$, while $C_R(z,t)$ is not, even at integer $t$.

Letting $z \mapsto -\frac{1}{z} $, gives 
$$C_L^i(z,t)=\eta(z+t)\circeq\exp(\frac{i2\pi t}{24})\: \eta(z)=C_R^i(z,t)$$

and the corresponding figure

[image]

$C_L^i(z,t)$ is annihilated by $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}-\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$, while $C_R^i(z,t)$ is not, even at integer $t$.

**I've scanned through quite a lot of papers containing info on the $\eta$-function yet haven't seen similar figures, but the Dedekind $\eta$ has been pretty well explored, so I was hoping someone could direct me to some references in the vast literature that might explain the geometry of such trajectories. (Obviously, a torus is evoked, but ....)**

I'm aware that E. Ghys deals with similar topics in "[Knots and Dynamics](http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~ghys/articles/icm.pdf)" (see also [Site1](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-lorenz) and [Site2](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/08/03/2006-icm-etienne-ghys-knots-and-dynamics/)), but I'm not sure (yet) how to clearly connect his arguments to the above curves.

Comment: Hi Tom--are these figures special to the $\eta$ function, or do similar figures arise if one makes similar parametric plots with some random analytic function (say a polynomial) instead?

Comment: Hi Dan--the results above depend on $\eta$ being a modular form. I don't see how to get the necessary periodicity with any polynomial under shear transformations. Scan my notes on Infinigens at my little "arxiv website" for details.

Comment: We're essentially looking at solns. around $z=0$ and infinity of the eigenfunction eqn.
$\exp(t\cdot z^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial z}) f(z)=f[z/(-tz+1)]=\epsilon(t) f(z)$ for some $t$. The simplest case being $f(z)=\exp(-\lambda/z)$. 

Comment: I wonder if the first curve could be lifted off the plane onto a double torus with one torus nested inside the other but sharing its circle of max radius with that of the other torus.

Comment: $C^i_R(zt)= f(qt)$ in the Ramanujan eta function identities on p. 375 of "Ramanujan’s Lost Notebook Part I" by George E. Andrews and Bruce C. Berndt.